# custom attribute UI in Magento admin

Tags: magento, attributes, admin

I'm trying to change the way Magento shows options of an attribute with multiple select.
I have 10K options for this attribute.
How can I override the UI and use an Ajax based UI?
The admin will be able to filter options and present only ~20 each time.
I know how to use js and php for this but not in Magento.

Thanks

Comment: did you find an answer to this?

Comment: I haven't done it, but try looking through the source of the Mage Bundle module. You'll see a bunch of Adminhtml blocks that create the grid. It's pretty involved though.

Comment: I think you will need to give you attrubute a custom frontend class in the database record in eav_attributes table. Then you can create this class and adjust the display of the field.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to rewrite block class responsible for this attribute.

```
<global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                     <catalog_product_edit_tabs_price>Company_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Tabs_Price</catalog_product_edit_tabs_price>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
</blocks>
</global>
```

Then in your Company_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Tabs_Price you can re-declare function responsible for logic for price attribute (for example).

You should have a good knowledge of Magento for this.